# "Cannot find variable: staticmethod" message while running Processing script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Every time I run my own processing script in QGIS 2.18.22 I get this message fifteen times in *Processing* tab in *Log Messages Panel* :

> 1  Cannot find variable: staticmethod
>   1  Cannot find variable: staticmethod
>   ...

I don't get any error message and the script works fine (at least I think so). After a while I noticed that my processing script has fifteen `staticmethod`s I defined in different classes. Numbers of the message increase when I add another `staticmethod`.

The outline of the script:

```
# Get parameters

# Import related packages

def RUN():
    pass 

class TOOL():    
    @staticmethod
    def Remove_Layers():
        pass 

    @staticmethod
    def Clear_Map_Canvas():
        pass       


class PROCESS():    
    @staticmethod
    def Centroids(points, field):
        pass 

    @staticmethod
    def Point_Grid_In_Region(gb, nat):
        pass            


RUN()
```

Why do I get this message and could it be affecting results of the script?